# Wordpress / PHP wildcard in if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line of code that works perfectly:

```
<?php if (in_category('CATEGORY-SUFFIX')) { get_header('SUFFIX'); } else { get_header(); } ?>
```

Except, I have a large number of categories and want to use a "wildcard" for the name of the category and have the header switch based on finding only a few characters in the category name.

Something more like:

```
<?php if (in_category('*SUFFIX')) { get_header('SUFFIX'); } else { get_header(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Categories are stored in the database so you will need something like:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

This should help you get the name of the page you are accessing at page load. Then you can do something like:

> get_header($cat_name);

**EDIT :**

Since you are looking just for a suffix, the best way to do this is either with something like strripos or a regular expression matching in an if/else structure or a switch statement depending on your needs:

```
//lets assume you want to catch all categories that end with ed (like teached)
if(strripos($cat_name,'ed', -2)!== FALSE){
   get_header('ed-header');
} elseif(...){
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have the if statement working... I just need to know how to not have to specify the exact name, but only a part of it - using a variable in place of part of the category name.

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood you here. I thought you had dynamic headers for each category. If that is the case you will need to do something like strpos and check for the suffix. I will update my answer.

Comment: That looks good, but I get an error: Notice: Undefined variable: cat_name in /var/www/site.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/theme/single.php on line 1. I'm not sure that the "$cat_name" is the correct request for wordpress - it was working with "in_category"

Comment: $cat_name is just a placeholder in my example. I am assuming it contains the categories name from something like: $cat_name = get_category(#category id OR name#);